# Not getting IP address of Client in Java Spring Web Application

Tags: apache, spring-mvc, servlets

I have a java Spring web application, deployed on an Apache server, in which I wish to capture IP address of client using the following code.

```
public static String getIpFromRequest(HttpServletRequest request){
          String remoteAddr = "";

            if (request != null) {
                remoteAddr = request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR");
                if (remoteAddr == null || "".equals(remoteAddr)) {
                    remoteAddr = request.getRemoteAddr();
                }
            }

            return remoteAddr;
    }
```

By this code I'm getting the same IP address for every client. I have referred all stackoverflow questions, but they suggested same above code. Please suggest possible way.

Comment: So what do you get, if not the IP address of the client ? null ? And empty address ? Another, possibly wrong address(how do you know it's wrong ) ?

Comment: Im getting another wrong IP address same for all client.

Comment: According to network team, it is a IP address of Load balancer. Hope you will get any idea from this.

Comment: Well ask your network team to have the load balancer set the necessary headers!!

Comment: Then perhaps you are not getting the X-FORWARDED-FOR header (you should verify whether you get your address from `request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR");` or from `request.getRemoteAddr();` .If your load balancer does not send the X_FORWARDED_FOR header, you need to ask the people responsible for your load balancer to configure it to add the X-FORWARDED-FOR header.